# Is there any possibility to remove unused css from the files?

Tags: css, optimization

I have lot of css files for my website and want to remove unused css from that files. Don't know which style is using for which purpose. Is there any tool or suggestions to remove unused styles for improving page optimisation.
Please suggest

Comment: You can use Purge CSS https://purgecss.com/ it was built for this exact reason.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [purifyCss](https://purifycss.online/) online tool to get the cleaned css , just enter you website url or provide html and css code

Answer (score 0):

You can try "web developer" chrome extension from chrome webstore